# Jquery, how can I avoid this selector duplication?

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
$('#barcode').JsBarcode($('#barcode').attr("data-barcode"), {
        format:"EAN"
        displayValue:true
        fontSize:10
        height: 22
        marginLeft: 10
        marginRight: 10
        marginTop: 3
        marginBottom: 0
      })
```

It's working, but I want to avoid the repetition. I try with `this` and `$this` without success...

Comment: `$this` and `this` only work within the context of a function.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#barcode')` is an object which can be put into a variable.

```
var barcode = $('#barcode');
barcode.JsBarcode(barcode.attr("data-barcode") ..
```